# How to insert the output of a command to variable in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Inside a batch file on Windows I would like some variable to have the output of `dir /b` command.

How this can be achieved ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381572/getting-log-message-from-svnlook-via-windows-batch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batch files didn't handle this use case very well. I did find one [thread that describes a technique using temporary files](http://weblogs.asp.net/lorenh/archive/2006/03/24/silly-batch-file-tricks-redirecting-stdout-into-an-evironment-variable-and-dp0.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, there's a better facility that comes pre-installed. Its called vbscript (and later there is Powershell ). Why don't you use vbscript instead.

```
strFolder="c:\test"
Set objFS = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )
Set objFolder = objFS.GetFolder(strFolder)
s=""
For Each strFile In objFolder.Files
    s=s & strFile & vbCrLf
Next
WScript.Echo s
```

The variable `s` now contains a list of files (equivalent to `dir` ). And if you want to store each filename into arrays, its also possible. (cmd.exe does not have arrays etc)

Comment: Just a note to whoever does not like this approach just because of not liking the VB syntax (such as myself) - the same utility (`wscript`/`cscript`, which comes with Windows) supports JScript (the Javascript engine of IE) too. I've recently built an entire build system using JScript, and it was pretty good because I like Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set LF=^


rem ** The two empty lines are NECESSARY
set output=
FOR /F %%i in ('dir /b') do SET output=!output!!LF!%%i
ECHO !output!
```