# Save command output to variable

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, cmd

In a batch file, I am trying to fetch the output of a command and save it to a variable.

The goal of my command is to count the number of folders in a certain folder.

- I can't use the trick provided in [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/110725/windows-command-prompt-how-to-get-the-count-of-all-files-in-current-directory/111215#111215) accepted answer because I would have to do `cd path\to\my\folder` to get to the current directory. Unfortunately, I can't do this command because `path\to\my\folder` is in fact a UNC path (`\\path\to\my\folder`), and `cd \\some\UNC\path` is not supported by the windows cmd.
- I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839375/how-to-insert-the-output-of-a-command-to-variable-in-a-batch-file/3839464#3839464) answer but I don't want to use a temporary file.

So I tried to do the following:

- To obtain the number of folders, I use:

  ```
  dir \\path\to\my\folder | find /c "<REP>"
  ```

  This works fine and returning me a number as I would expect.
- To retrieve the output of this command in a batch variable, I tried:

  ```
  FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%i IN ('\\path\to\my\folder | find /c "<REP>"') DO 
  SET value = %%i
  ```

  But without success, the error message being...

  > | was unexpected.

  ...when I execute the batch file and...

  > %%i was unexpected.

  when I try to execute the command directly in a command window. I tried to escape the quotes around the `<REP>` string (`...find /c ""<REP>""') DO...`), got me the same error.

Am I on the right path to retrieve the output in a variable? What should I do to resolve the error message?
Or maybe there is a simpler way to set a command output in a variable?

Comment: Addressing the issues you've encountered: 1) `|` should be escaped in that context like this: `^|`, and 2) `%%i` is only used in batch files, and `%i` is its counterpart for using directly at the command prompt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture output command CMD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646575/capture-output-command-cmd)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the answer you first mentioned. You don't have to `cd` there, but you can use `pushd` which will allocate a temporary drive letter for UNC paths which will be released when you do a `popd`.

So in essence:

```
pushd \\server\path
set count=0
for /d %%x in (*) do set /a count+=1
popd
```