# Storing return value of a command in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am creating a batch file, in which I want to store the value returned by the following command (in Windows):

```
netstat -an | find ":port" /c
```

How to store the count value and print using echo?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture output command CMD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646575/capture-output-command-cmd).  Also, you may find this useful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/07/31/10334556.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To capture the output of a command, you can use the `for /F` command; to store it into a variable, use `set` in the body of the `for` loop:

```
for /F "delims=" %L in ('netstat -an ^| find ":port" /c') do (set "VAR=%L")
```

Note the escaped pipe `^|`. To use this within a batch file, replace `%L` by `%%L`.

This only works for a single-line output. If a command returns a multi-line output, only the last line is stored in variable `VAR`.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess something similar to:

```
@echo off
set "Blah=netstat -an|find ":port" /c"
echo %Blah%
pause
```

Comment: Its printing zero , where as when I run the netstat command  in cmd ,the answer is 12

Comment: This method captures the exit code of the process, but not its text output.