# Batch - Command output to variable

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to assign a command output to a variable for later use, without the use of temp files. Following answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203629/batch-assign-command-output-to-variable), using `for /f "delims=" %%i in ('command') do set output=%%i`, the prompt flashes too fast so I can't read the error message.

The command in question is `echo ;%PATH%; | find /C /I "%PATH2%"` where %PATH2% is an earlier set variable containing the path to the python folder. I'm trying to check if the user has the path set, and depending on that continue on. So I want to assign the command output from that command to a variable, in this case "output".

Comment: Why can't you use temporary files?

Comment: Do not double-click the batch-file, open a command prompt window and run it from there, then you can read its output and error messages... You will need to escape the pipe symbol like `^|` within a command line parsed by `for /F`...

Comment: You can also add @pause at the end of your batch file, this way it will wait for an input before to close

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture output command CMD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646575/capture-output-command-cmd)