# Divide number from wc in bash + batch

Tags: bash, batch-file, git-bash

So I'm trying to loop over a bunch of PDF files, grab their character count and divide that by 5. So output should be something like this:

```
PDF1.pdf
400

PDF2.pdf
1000
```

Assuming `PDF1.pdf` has 2000 characters and `PDF2.pdf` has 5000 characters. This is what I'm currently doing:

```
for %%f in (*.pdf) do (
    echo %%~nf.pdf
    pdftotext %%~nf.pdf -enc UTF-8 - | wc -m
)
```

What I really seek help with, is grabbing the value from `wc -m`, divide that by 5 and echo it out.

I've tried various things such as `SET /A total=(wc -m) / 5` but nothing really seems to work out.

Comment: Also closely related to [Capture output command CMD](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14646575)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for %%f in (*.pdf) do (
 echo %%~nf.pdf
 for /f %%c in ('pdftotext %%~nf.pdf -enc UTF-8 - ^| wc -m') do set /a words=%%c / 5
 call echo %%words%%
)
```

should do the trick. Single-quote the command yielding the word-count - note the caret to escape the pipe. Assign the required value to `words` and use the `call echo` trick to produce the result.

There are other possibilities...

---

With decimals...

```
 for /f %%c in ('pdftotext %%~nf.pdf -enc UTF-8 - ^| wc -m') do set /a words=%%c*2
 call echo %%words:~0,-1%%.%%words:~-1%%.
```

Multiply by 2=required value *10; show all-bar-last-char, dot, last-char.

Comment: Hell yeah! That did it. Any clue how I could get it out with decimals? Right now it rounds it down.

Comment: The decimals didn't really work. I got `14100.6.` when I should get about `29.1114` in this case.

Comment: Er, which case? What was `%%c` to display that? Batch is actually limited to integers. How do you get `29.1114` by dividing an integer by 5? It would mean that `wc` is returning 145.557 words.

Comment: 145557 words sounds about right yeah. I tagged this post with bash as well, as I'm using Git Bash to run the commands, otherwise won't `pdftotext` and `wc` work

Comment: 145557 gave me 29111.4 using the method I've shown. What thousands/decimal separators are you using?

Comment: Ahh dammit, I got it right now. Wrong folder and wrong files!! Sorry, man. Works great! Thanks a lot!