# How to create condition find number of file in batch file

Tags: batch-file

Can you help me please, I would like to create batch for count number of file start with key word "MM_" in this path.

```
D:\>dir /o | find "MM_"
27/06/2017  01:14 PM             1,592 MM_170613.csv
27/06/2017  01:14 PM             1,376 MM_170614.csv
27/06/2017  01:13 PM             2,223 MM_170615.csv
27/06/2017  01:12 PM             2,241 MM_170616.csv
27/06/2017  01:11 PM             2,497 MM_170617.csv
```

I have use command as Stephan provide as follow detail

`@ECHO OFF
C:
cd "C:\MyDir"
set cntAAA = dir /b *MM_*|find /c /v "" 
echo %cntAAA%`

Result is show

`0
echo off`

Somebody can help?

Comment: `find /?` states a `/c` parameter to count... `dir /b *MM_*|find /c /v ""`

Comment: You need [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) to capture the output of a command (line)...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture output command CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646575/capture-output-command-cmd)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```bat
@Echo Off
CD /D "C:\MyDir"
Set "cntAAA=Dir/B "MM_*.csv"|Find /C /V """ 
%cntAAA%
Pause
```