# OutPut of an EXE application in Command or Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I have a simple Console application which returns a int value out , 
when i run this application from command , How do i capture the Out put ?
Code

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
            return 1;
}
```

I used the following line of Command

```
for /f %a in ('D://Test//ConsoleApplication1//ConsoleApplication1//bin//Debug//ConsoleApplication1.exe') do set "dow=%a"
```

When i output `echo %dow%` , it prints what is in front of echo and not the value .

Comment: What do you mean by "in front of the echo?" Please show your `echo` command. Are you running both commands (the `for` and the `echo`) from the prompt or in a batch? Are you aware that the path-separator for windows is a backslash, not two successive forward-slashes?

Comment: Replace `//` by `\ `and double the percent-sign in `%a`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture output command CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646575/capture-output-command-cmd)

Comment: batch file or cmdline?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard i m first trying in a command line ,later will be moving to batch

Comment: @Magoo I meant when i tried to ouput the variable

Comment: ok, so do you want the full `static int Main(string[] args)
{
            return 1;
}` as the output?

Comment: no i just want 1 , the returned value

Comment: Have you shown us your `echo` command yet?

Comment: C:\Windows\system32>for /f %a in ('D:\test\ConsoleApplication1\Consol
eApplication1\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe') do set "dow=%a"

C:\Windows\system32>echo %dow%
%dow%

Comment: Please check the suggested duplicate. Although that question specified Windows XP, it applies equally to subsequent versions of Windows.

Comment: Additionally, if you have an EXE that exits returning a value, that value will be interpreted as `%ERRORLEVEL%`.

Comment: I m running this on a windows server 2012r2

Comment: @JeffZeitlin how do i use the ErrorLevel , can you send the full command , I m pretty new to this

Comment: I _strongly_ suggest you find some batch references - I generally use [SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/) for batch. The use of `%ERRORLEVEL%` is very nearly a _fundamental_ part of batch.

Answer (score 0):

You can create bat file next to your exe file and write inside bat this:

```
YourExeApp.exe > d:\test.txt
```

Don´t use C:\test.txt directly. Use rather C:\test\test.txt