# Batch For Loop - Error running python command

Tags: python, windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to run this base64 decode in a FOR loop -

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%a IN (file.txt) DO (
     FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%g IN (`echo %%a | python -m base64 -d`) do (SET "decode1=%%g")
<nul set /p =!decode1! >> new2.txt
echo. >> new2.txt
)
```

I get error that pipe "|" was unexpected at this time.

If I run this other example, it works fine -

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%a IN (file.txt) DO (
echo %%a | python -m base64 -d > temp.txt
set /p var1=<temp.txt
<nul set /p =!var1! >> new.txt
echo. >> new.txt
)
```

I'm just trying to get the python output into a variable right away instead of fiddling around as in the second example. Can it be done?

Here is the structure of my file.txt. It is simple. It has multiple lines (a few hundred) with 2 columns of base64 that need decoding into a new.txt file with a space between each column just like in file.txt.

file.txt

```
Q2FTZlpsZXhlR2dWNWV2Mkxsd0JQdw== Ylk5VEh3M1dRSFhqUHV2WjlMcURyZw==
ZDRhMHhHbndLTDBKa3A4S0piSlB2dw== NWxVODVSNEJUUVZpMGx0UHNERVJvQQ==
RHBHTEFfS0poWWlXbnI3c3NFUzlHQQ== RUcwb3dUWmNYM2UtMzBKVFhOWk1uQQ==
Z3RvanZRMUloMzhsYjkyVXNpNTZ1Zw== LW5rLXdndmYyYzRDLW9oNWg1Nk1Udw==
```

Comment: Did you try escaping the pipe with a caret?

Comment: yes, I just tried it and it works, silly me.

Comment: Update - just checked the output, it's missing my exclamation marks.

Comment: I'd also add quotes to `set /P ="!decode1!"`; anyway, [`CertUtil`](https://ss64.com/nt/certutil.html) is also capable of en-/decoding Base64, so you wouldn't even have to call Python from the batch file...

Comment: Take also a look at this: [Save command output to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8166271)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
python -c "import base64, sys; f=open('file.txt', 'rb'); [print(base64.b64decode(lines.split()[0]).decode(), base64.b64decode(lines.split()[1]).decode()) for lines in f]; f.close()" > new2.txt
```

This avoids the *fiddling around* with a `for` loop...`set /p` etc. and lets Python read `file.txt` and redirect the output to `new2.txt`. If output file encoding is an issue then perhaps Python could do the write as well.

Tested with Python 3.8 if that matters.

Comment: Do I put that line into my batch file? I'm not a Python coder so it's a basic question. Ok, just tried it and it's looking promising. I'm going to specify how my file.txt is structured in the question above to see if this command line can do what I need. Please look at question again.

Comment: `file.txt` seems like a unusual structure so the updated answer follows the token concept shown in the question. Note that in the source of `base64` shows a file input argument, if the file is wanted to be encoded or decoded all at once.

Comment: Thanks, that's nearly working 100%. My sample above does decode fine, but some of my other lines in column 1 have no == in them and these ARE decoded but the second column is not decoded.

Comment: I think it has to do with number of spaces between the strings. It can vary. Can your code jump across multiple spaces after column 1 to decode column 2?

Comment: Update - I did a quick google and I removed the "split" parameters and now it works good. Thanks!

Comment: Removed `b' '` arguments from `split` methods. Now splits on multiple spaces instead of single space.

Comment: One last question on this - instead of my file containing the two columns as shown in the example, how could this command line be edited to make it decode only on columns 5 and 6 using one or more spaces as delimiters instead of columns 1 and 2?

Answer (score 1):

The main issue in your code is the lack of escaping as demonstrated in [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14646731) and also [this related comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8166271#comment10035201_8166271):

```cmd
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%g IN (`echo %%a | python -m base64 -d`) do (SET "decode1=%%g")
```

should read:

```cmd
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%g IN (`echo %%a ^| python -m base64 -d`) do (SET "decode1=%%g")
```

in order to hide the pipe `|` from the first parsing phase that processes the whole `for /F` loop definition.

In addition, I recommend to use `set /p ="!decode1!"` rather than `set /p =!decode1!` in order to preserve surrounding quotation marks that could be present in the value of variable `decode1`.

---

Anyway, I want to provide an alternative method of your conversion approach, based on the tool [`certutil`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/certutil), which is available since Windows XP, I think:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_SEP= "                        & rem // (separator character or string for the output)
set "_TMP=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.tmp" & rem // (temporary file for conversion of single items)
set "_CHR=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.chr" & rem // (temporary file to hold just a given separator)

rem // Create a temporary file that only contains a single separator as specified:
> nul forfiles /P "%~dp0." /M "%~nx0" /C "cmd /V /C ^> 0x22!_CHR!0x22 echo(!_SEP!0x1A"
> nul copy "%_CHR%" /A + nul "%_CHR%" /B
rem // Loop through all non-empty lines read from the console input:
for /F "tokens=* eol= " %%L in ('more') do (
    rem // Explicitly deny wildcard characters that would cause problems with a `for` loop later:
    for /F "delims=*?<> eol=*" %%C in ("%%L") do if not "%%C"=="%%L" (
        >&2 echo "%%L" contains forbidden characters!
    ) else (
        rem // Loop through whitespace-separated items in the current line:
        set "FIRST=#"
        for %%I in (%%L) do (
            rem // Check current items against list of all valid characters for Base64 encoding:
            (
                for /F "delims=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/= eol==" %%D in ("%%I") do rem/
            ) && (
                >&2 echo "%%I" is not valid Base64 encoding!
            ) || (
                rem // Actually perform the Base64 decoding of the current item:
                > "%_TMP%" echo(%%I
                > nul certutil -f -v -decode "%_TMP%" "%_TMP%"
                rem // Write the resulting data to the console output:
                if not defined FIRST type "%_CHR%"
                type "%_TMP%"
                set "FIRST="
            )
        )
        if not defined FIRST echo/
    )
)
rem // Clean up temporary files:
del "%_TMP%" "%_CHR%"

endlocal
exit /B
```

This script, let us call it `decode-b64-chunks.bat`, reads Base64-encoded data from the console and writes the decoded data to the console. To convert the sample input file `file.txt` from your question to a new file in the current working directory, use the following command line:

```cmd
decode-b64-chunks.bat < "file.txt" > "new.txt"
```

The resulting file named `new.txt` will eventually contain the following text:

> ```cmd
> CaSfZlexeGgV5ev2LlwBPw bY9THw3WQHXjPuvZ9LqDrg
> d4a0xGnwKL0Jkp8KJbJPvw 5lU85R4BTQVi0ltPsDERoA
> DpGLA_KJhYiWnr7ssES9GA EG0owTZcX3e-30JTXNZMnA
> gtojvQ1Ih38lb92Usi56ug -nk-wgvf2c4C-oh5h56MTw
> ```

---

The above script contains two particular portions of code I want to go into:

1. Explicitly deny wildcard characters that would cause problems with a `for` loop later:

   ```cmd
       for /F "delims=*?<> eol=*" %%C in ("%%L") do if not "%%C"=="%%L" (
           >&2 echo "%%L" contains forbidden characters!
       ) else (
           …
       )
   ```

   `%%L` contains the current line string. The `delims` option of the `for /F` loop lists all wildcard characters (`*` and `?` are well known, but `<` and `>` are undocumented ones). So if the current line contains one such character, `for /F` will tokenise it in some way, so its meta-variable `%%C` does not equal the original line string in `%%L`, then the whole line is skipped and an error message is returned.

   The reason for excluding such lines is the loop `for %%I in (%%L) do`, which is used to walk through the whitespace-separated items in a line. A standard `for` loop (no `/F` switch) is intended to loop through files, but it actually only accesses the file system when at least a wildcard character is encountered, which is what I want to prevent.
2. Check current items against list of all valid characters for Base64 encoding:

   ```cmd
               )
                   for /F "delims=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/= eol==" %%D in ("%%I") do rem/
               ) && (
                   >&2 echo "%%I" is not valid Base64 encoding!
               ) || (
                   …
               )
   ```

   The `delims` option lists all characters that are permitted in a Base64-encoded string. Now if an item `%%I` contains only such characters, it is a delimiter-only line, which `for /F` skips; if any other character occurs, `for /F` processes the text, although nothing happens as there is only `rem/` in the loop body. Anyway, I just want to know whether `for /F` iterates or not, because then I know if the processed item is valid Base64-encoded data.

   The clue here is that `for /F` (opposed to any other `for` loops) resets the exit code when it iterates at least once and sets it when it does not. The conditional operator `&&` executes the following code only when the exit code is zero, so when the `for /F` loop iterated, which means a forbidden character is encountered, in which case the current item is skipped and an error message is returned. The conditional operator `||` executes the following block when the exit code is not zero, so the item contains valid Base64-encoded data.

Comment: Well, thanks, that's very thorough for sure. It will take me a while to understand it.